# enumerate environment and graphics

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

If I have an item in an `enumerate` environment, which only contains a figure (or table etc), the bullet point of the enumerations alignment goes weird. For example:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
    Dummy item
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ |  p{4.5cm}  | c | c |}
                \hline
                Col & More col & Even more col  \\ 
                \hline
                one & two & three  \\
                \hline

            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Makes the bullet points misalign, ie. (b)(i) and (a) are not aligned.

If I add some text before the figure, it goes back to normal. For example,

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
    Dummy item
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item
         Dummy text to make it align nicely.
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ |  p{4.5cm}  | c | c |}
                \hline
                Col & More col & Even more col  \\ 
                \hline
                one & two & three  \\
                \hline

            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

So, is there any way of adding a line of "invisible" text or something along those lines to fix this layout issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `\mbox{}`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Dummy item
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item \mbox{}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ |  p{4.5cm}  | c | c |}
    \hline
    Col & More col & Even more col  \\ 
    \hline
    one & two & three  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]